# Ibatis map List<T> into @Result

Tags: mybatis, ibatis, mybatis-mapper

I have a situation like, i write query in  Mapper java class (Ibatis) to fetch List values. Inside this ParentPojo i have List along with that some other fields like num, name.

ChildPojo contains field as a1,a2,a3.

Sample ParentPojo:

```
private String num;
private String name;
private List<ChildPojo> childPojo = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now i write a query to return list of values and trying to map like the below, but the below does not work

```
@Results( value = {
@Result(property= "num" , column = "numColumn"),
@Result(property = "name", column= "name",
@Result(property = "childPojo[0].a1", column ="a1"),
@Result(property = "childPojo[0].a2", column ="a2"),
@Result(property = "childPojo[0].a3", column ="a3")
})
```

When i do this i get indexOutOfBound error.

Comment: This mapping is not possible with annotations right now. You need to declare `<resultMap />` with `<collection />` in a XML mapper.

Comment: can we do it <script> with in mapper class? Or do we need to do in xml files

Comment: `<script />` is valid only in statement annotations (i.e. `@Select`, `@Insert`, etc.). You may need XML for this.